# fatal exception asynctask #2 AndroidRuntime

Tags: java, android

FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 in my application. Can somebody please tell me why and also tell me what I need to do. I am pretty confused right now and need a little help.

here is my code

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DataActivity.this);
    Id = b.getString("Id");
    Exists = b.getBoolean("Exists");

    final String myUrl = "http://xxxxxxxxxx/api.php?id="+Id;
    try
    {
        new MyAsyncTaskGetNews().execute(myUrl,"false");
    }catch (Exception e){Log.d("d2",e.toString());}


    IB = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    IB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try
            {
                new MyAsyncTaskGetNews().execute(myUrl,"true");
            }catch (Exception e){Log.d("d1",e.toString());}
        }
    });
```

and the logcat

```
07-25 19:47:25.393 8717-9017/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                Process: com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx, PID: 8717
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                                    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:359)
                                                                    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:105)
                                                                    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:266)
                                                                    at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.DataActivity$MyAsyncTaskGetNews.doInBackground(DataActivity.java:136)
                                                                    at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.DataActivity$MyAsyncTaskGetNews.doInBackground(DataActivity.java:93)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                    at 

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
07-25 19:47:25.533 8717-8717/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7d8aadd time:35310450
07-25 19:47:25.705 8717-8717/com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.DataActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{afa2ab V.E...... R......D 0,0-1026,483} that was originally added here
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:372)
                                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
                                                                       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:86)
                                                                       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:326)
                                                                       at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.DataActivity$MyAsyncTaskGetNews.onPreExecute(DataActivity.java:105)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
                                                                       at com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx.DataActivity$1.onClick(DataActivity.java:87)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5280)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21239)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: In order to help with the exception, we need to see the AsyncTask class

Answer (score 0):

Your async task GetNews is creating a Handler in doInBackground.  It can't do that.  If it needs to create a Handler to post to the UI thread, it should do so in onPreExecute.  But really an AsyncTask should never need to do that, it should use onPostExecute and publishProgress/onProgress to avoid the need to do that.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: You cannot create a new Handler on a Thread, such as doInBackground of an AsyncTask.  It has to be created on either the UI thread, or a thread that has called Looper.loop().  SO you're creating the Handler in the wrong place.  However chances are good you don't need a Handler at all, and there's better ways of doing what you're trying to do.